# What is the best strategy for searching multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I currently have 10 almost identical tables, 1 for each section of content in my app. There are no queries in my app that access more than 1 of these tables at a time.

## Option 1

Create a single `articles` **table** having all fields the multiple tables have in common. Add a new `section` **field** indicating the old table name.

Reduce each of the 10 original tables fields to only the 4 or 5 fields that were unique to that section.

Add a foreign key pointing to the original record in the articles table.
Rename the 10 tables to start with the prefix **"extra_"**.

Create 10 views that inner join the articles table to each extra_ table.
These views would have the same name as the original 10 tables.

Thoughts:

Since the resulting views would contain all the fields from the original there would be very little existing PHP/SQL code that needs updating.

If I can't INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE against the views I'd need to make many changes to existing PHP code.

Adding to the articles table a new field and making it available in the views requires recreating 10 views.

Removing from the articles table a field which was used in the views requires recreating 10 views.

... other benefits or drawbacks?

## Option 2

Keep the current 10 tables, create a view that `UNION ALL`s all the tables together.

Thoughts:

Changes to any of the 10 tables requires recreating only 1 view. Zero changes needed to existing PHP code.

... other benefits or drawbacks?

## Option 3

Do everything in PHP. Make an array listing all the tables and which fields are desired from them. Dynamically generate and search the big `UNION` SQL query with PHP.

#### Anyone have a better suggestion or advice on the options proposed?

Comment: When making queries, do you more often access all or most of the 10 tables? Or are the queries typically limited to one of the 10 tables at a time?

Comment: Queries are limited to 1 of the 10 at a time... ... I'm almost certain 100% of current queries related to those tables are 1 at a time.

Comment: Taking that into account and the fact the tables are not exactly the same, I expect I would keep them separate. Then query each table individually in my PHP code when needed.

Comment: I will just leave this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Option 1 (or 1a) Side effect is that the app does not need 10 queries anymore, but only needs one.

Comment: Sounds to me like the tables are very similar. This means they should be merged. After you are done merging the tables, you should try to find out what got you into this situation and try to avoid it in the future. It's usually bad planning, and sloppy/quick development.

Comment: The table structure at the moment. More custom fields will be added to all of them sooner than later.
http://i.imgur.com/CpfEY2x.png

Comment: Is the _data_ the same across the common fields in the 10 tables?  If so, then you definitely should do some reorganizing.  If the _data_ varies, then what's wrong with the current setup, other than having to set the table name when doing a query?  I hear a contradiction; please clarify:  "create a view with a UNION" versus "Queries are limited to 1 of the 10 at a time".

Comment: Rick James: At the moment no current queries access more than 1 at a time, but client wants the ability to do a database-wide search which would search all at the same time, hence the question "What is the best strategy for searching multiple tables?".  

The data is the same for all the common fields. Uncommon fields, even when the field name is the same, might contain different data or the same kind of data but the data is used differently by the php code.